# Why changes to any partition with a lower number than a mounted partition are not permitted?

Tags: partitioning, mount

I was looking at [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518965/help-managing-ubuntu-14-04-partition-size/518967?noredirect=1#comment705074_518967) and Marty Fried says "In fact, you can't even do anything to any partition with a lower number than a mounted partition." referring to changing sizes of this partitions.

Since I didn't want to make unrelated comments to that answer I decided to ask a new question here.

Why can't changes to partitions with number bellow the mounted one be done? I understand why changes in the mounted one can't be done, but not this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Marty may be generalizing. You can make changes to partitions before a mounted partition that do not affect the mounted partition. So you can shrink them, but not expand. 
[image]

[image]

[image]