# Missing HDD Partition After creating dual-boot with K-Ubuntu and Windows 7

Tags: windows, hard-drive, kubuntu, swap

I had some requirements which made me decide to install `K-Ubuntu` with parallel `Windows-7` OS. I made some free space on a separate partition and booted the system with a bootable pen-drive with `K-Ubuntu_16.04`. The problems that occurred are as follows :

1. After installation when I restarted the system, the was no `boot-loader` for K-Ubuntu. If there is a pen-drive  in one the `USB` slots, K-Ubuntu boots up as per the `boot-order`. Else if there is no pen-drive then Windows-7 is booted up automatically.
2. When the `Windows-OS` boots up, I am unable to find my `D: drive` (which,by the way was not the K-Ubuntu installation target drive.) which was a totally independent drive with my movies and other stuff.

While K-Ubuntu boots up from pen-drive, all the drives are present and accessible in the `Ubuntu file-explorer`. All I need is a K-Ubuntu OS selection option boot-loader screen and all partitions should be available on both the Operating Systems.

It is a high probability that there is not a boot-loader showing up for OS because the K-Ubuntu was nevr properly installed in the first place.

Comment: Where did you install the bootloader? You can install it in either MBR or on a separate partition. If updates for windows 7 are disabled then install the GRUB bootloader in the MBR. It is much faster and easier. Otherwise install the bootloader into a separate partition and create a boot entry with EasyBCD. Creating a boot entry is somewhat complicated for Ubuntu .

Comment: I wonder if the bootable pen drive was detected as /dev/sda and your hdd detected as /dev/sdb. You install Kubuntu to the hdd (/dev/sdb) and all goes well. When you reboot, without the usb pen, the hdd is detected as /dev/sda.as it is the only drive now in the system. Boot from the Kubuntu usb pen again, open a terminal and type 'sudo fdisk 'l', see which device is assigned to which disk.

Comment: @AshishKafle Thank you for you advice. I used `EasyBCD` to repair `Boot-Files` and it was so smooth.

Comment: @hatterman I think the reason is K-Ubuntu was never properly installed on the system. My`BIOS` has `external-drives` on top of the list for boot-priority. With no pen-drive it automatically goes to boot up `Windows-7` whih shows that there is no `linux-OS` found on any of the partitions.

Answer (score 1):

From the situation it seems a bit clear that the installation of `Ubuntu OS` (K-Ubuntu,in this case) was never completed on the desired machine/partition. For if it were successfully done, there would have appeared a `grub-menu` for OS selection which would list all the Operating-Systems installed on the HDD.

Secondly, about the partition which was untouched during Ubuntu installation and still can't be seen in the windows-explorer, it is so because that partiton was made a [swap-partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508870/what-is-a-swap-area) forcefully during linux/ubuntu installation. Since, you cannot access any partitions with linux files on it through a Windows-explorer thus, this partition also goes invisible when one tries to search for it in Windows-OS.

So,following steps would successfully install a `Linux` flavor on the desired partition keeping other partitions visible as well as accessible in Windows:

1- Shrink the existing partitions and create a pool of free space for Linux/Ubuntu installation and swap-disk allocation.

2- Create a `New-Volume` for `swap` purpose from the free-space created in the first step. This disk should have memory equal to the `physical-memory (RAM)`the target machine. For further clarification regarding swap-memory reservation check this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62073/how-to-decide-on-swap-size).

3- System now must still have some free-space left (linux/ubuntu os will be installed on this free-space). This should be kept around `20-30 gigs`. I myself kept it to 50-GB since i had a list of installations coming my way on the `linux/ubuntu OS`. Leave this space as free.

4- Make a bootable external-drive with the desired OS (K-Ubuntu 16.04, here).I would recommend [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/).

5- Move up the `extrernal-disk` to the top on boot-priority list from the `BIOS`.

6- Restart the system with external drive in place and initiate the Ubuntu installation process.Manually setup the `installation-partition` and `swap-partition`. Select the 'free-space' you created earlier as the primary partition for Ubuntu-installation and hit next.

7- A prompt will ask to confirm if one wants to allocate a partition for `swapping` or not. This is where you have to hit the back button and select the `New-Volume` that was created earlier. Hit `Install` and sit back while the ubuntu gets installed.

8- Restart the system without the USB. A boot-loader menu will ask you to select an OS to boot with. Select Ubuntu and patrol the whole OS to check if everything it working smooth.

9- Restart the system and boot the Windows-OS. Check for the partitions you expect to be visible and accessible.

You would not be able to see the partitions where Ubuntu/Linux is installed and the partition allotted for swapping. Remaining partition would be accessible and writable permanently.