# Is there any way to extend root filesystem ext4 space using home ext4?

Tags: 18.04

Some months ago I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS on my new laptop, but while allocating space to the drivers, I unknowingly put 20 GB for the root filesystem partition 3 Ext4 (which now I think it's a disk where everything is going to be installed). So my question is, is there any way to increase its size without formatting it again using 70-80 GB of home ext4 space.

You can see the picture of GParted and free-h which I have attached within this question for a better understanding of my problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: You probably don't need 30GB swap. See [How to decide on Swap size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62073/how-to-decide-on-swap-size) for more information.

Comment: Edit your question and show me a screenshot of `gparted` (not `Disks`) and I can make a better recommendation. What's on p7? Also show me `free -h`.

Comment: @heynnema I have edited my question and per your request, i have also uploaded the gparted command screeshot.

Comment: My current thinking is to (outline only): temporarily disable swap, comment out the swap line in /etc/fstab, remove your excessive p6 swap partition, resize p3, create a /swapfile, edit /etc/fstab to enable /swapfile. Have you used `gparted` and `terminal` before? I'll post a detailed answer if you accept my thinking.

Comment: @heynnema I tried your solution and now I have reduced swap size into 5 GB but now I have another problem. P3 disk has some problem related to unallocated. Can you help me to solve it? I have attached a new picture within this question please check it.

Comment: Looks like the filesystem did not grow with the partition (some partitions tools run resize2fs and some don't).  You can run sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1p3 yourself.

Comment: @DMC-416 You can use `gparted`s Partition/Check to fix it, or use `resize2fs` as shown in ubfan1's comment. You **must** do this from a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

Comment: @heynnema Thank you for your quick comment. I run it in the terminal and it worked like a cream. But now ubuntu has become slow compared to previous, I mean to say, it takes 3-4 minutes to restart ( I think this is bcoz of the swap. It get off automatically) and I have to select Swapon (on GParted) every time otherwise, it goes off automatically whenever I restart the pc. I ran this code (sudo chmod -R a+rwx /etc) to edit the comment of etc/fstab
Any suggestion to solve this.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sudo blkid` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`. **You shouldn't have chmod'ed /etc**... sigh. I'm sure that it'll break the OS.

Comment: @heynnema According to the man resize2fs output, an ext4 filesystem may be expanded when mounted (with any recent kernel).

Comment: @ubfan1 OP already got into trouble using `gparted` on live partitions. That's why the FS was off in the first place. Safest way is to do it when booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

Comment: @heynnema This problem start to occur after I remove swap and again re-created it with a small size (while re-creating I suppose swap UUID changed to the new one and the new UUID was not automatically replaced in /etc/fstab section). After I ran sudo blkid and grep -i swap /etc/fstab as per ur suggestion, I figured out this problem. Now, I have changed the /etc/fstab swap UUID with the new one and it worked. 

Thank you for your helpful comment.
It really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments... here's an **outline** of one way to resize your root file system, by deleting your swap partition, resizing /, and using a /swapfile, instead of a swap partition...

- temporarily disable swap

  - sudo swapoff -a
- comment out the swap line in /etc/fstab

  - #UUID=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx none  swap       sw       0       0
- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB

  - delete your excessive p6 swap partition using `gparted`
  - resize p3 using `gparted`
- boot back into Ubuntu
- create a 4G /swapfile

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

<strike>sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap</strike>

sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm xG RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this /swapfile line at the end of /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines...

To edit, use `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```